# Не сработало min-height:100%

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как правильно сверстать макет, в котором у `<body>` есть свой `background`, а содержимое страницы - один `<div>` по центру экрана c минимальной высотой в 100% экрана и своим `background`.

В моем варианте я ожидал, что футер прижмется к низу страницы, а `.container` растянется, но почему-то не сработало свойство `min-height:100%`.

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kthv5uo5/).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kthv5uo5/1/

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/kthv5uo5/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kthv5uo5/3/

Comment: @Get
1)Если содержимое больше высота экрана, то темный `background` не сохранится при скроле.

2) Ваш Update тоже имеет разрыв белого `background` если содержимого меньше чем высота экрана